# How to use value after checking if exists in a list using 'any' command python

Tags: python

I am trying to check if an entered value is in a list of values and then use it if it does using the `any` command in an `if` statement. But for some reason when the command finished iterating through the list it won't let me use this value.
Can someone where do I neeed to change my code to make it work?.
I want to print the `key` in the end.

This is the mentioned if statement:

```
if any(SHA3_256.new(key.export_key()).hexdigest() == hashed_pk for key in publicKeys):
                print(key)
```

### **Code Parameters:**

- `publicKeys` is a list of string:
  `["key1", "key2"]`...
- `hashed_ok` is the entered string: `"0c22352b43d1696ac069a15a3561c9fc4c731e4e458edb7f648544b779f341dd"`.

Comment: try to put 'for' loop outside of 'if' condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `any` use `next`, which retrieves the first value valid in a generator, and use the guard expression as a filter clause, this way:

```
key = next((key for key in publicKeys if SHA3_256.new(key.export_key()).hexdigest() == hashed_pk), "Key not found")
print(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
for key in publicKeys:
    if SHA3_256.new(key.export_key()).hexdigest() == hashed_pk:
        print(key)
        # Use `break` here if you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new `:=` assignment for this if you still wanted to keep it as a one liner. An example would be

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3]
if any((key := k) == 2 for k in lst):
    print(key)
```

So in your case

```py
if any(SHA3_256.new((key := k).export_key()).hexdigest()) == hashed_pk for k in publicKeys):
    print(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the most elegant thing to do, but in Python 3.8+, you can use the [walrus operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) (`:=`) :

```
if any(SHA3_256.new((correct_key:=key).export_key()).hexdigest() == hashed_pk for key in publicKeys):
    print(correct_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables only exist in the scope in which they're defined. In this case, you're defining `any` only in the scope of that list comprehension, which is closed before your `print(key)` statement.

My personal view is that that sort of pythonic one-line list comprehension is great for trivially simple cases, but annoying to parse the moment you're trying to do multiple things. I would just use `for key in publicKeys:`  syntax and have your check and print statements in that block.